# WPF MVVM LiveCharts how to show X axis Label?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, livecharts

I'm having hard times to show some simple labels in my Cartesian Bar Charts, I'm reading a lot around but nothing seems to work for me. I'm using the MVVM pattern in my project, so this is the code I have so far..

**VIEW**

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="2" Series="{Binding ChartDataSets}">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis LabelsRotation="20" Labels="{Binding ColumnLabels}" Position="RightTop" >
            <lvc:Axis.Separator >
                <lvc:Separator Step="1"></lvc:Separator>
            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}" Position="RightTop"></lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

**DataModel**

class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private double value;
public double Value
{
get => this.value;
set
{
this.value = value;
OnPropertyChanged();
}
}

```
private string label;
public string Label
{
    get => this.label;
    set
    {
        this.label = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Label");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

}

**ViewModel**

```
class BackupStatsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ChartValues<DataModel> values = new ChartValues<DataModel>();
    public SeriesCollection ChartDataSets { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ColumnLabels { get; set; }
    public class ErrorPrt
    {
        public ErrorPrt(){
            prtName = string.Empty;
            Count = -1;
        }
        public string prtName { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
    public BackupStatsViewModel()
    {
        InitializeBarChartData();
    }
    private void InitializeBarChartData()
    {

        this.ColumnLabels = new ObservableCollection<string>(values.Select(dataModel => dataModel.Label));
        var dataMapper = new CartesianMapper<DataModel>()
          .Y(dataModel => dataModel.Value)
          .Fill(dataModel => dataModel.Value > 15.0 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green);

        this.ChartDataSets = new SeriesCollection
        {
          new ColumnSeries
          {
            Values = values,
            Configuration = dataMapper,
            DataLabels = true
          }
          
        };
    }
    public ErrorPrt[] PrtCount(List<DataRow> rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DataRow>> grouped = rows.GroupBy(s => s.Field<string>(2));
        ErrorPrt[] err = new ErrorPrt[grouped.Count()];
        //Omitted code for sake of brevity
        
        ErrorPrt[] arr = err.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
            values.Add(new DataModel() { Label = $"PRT {arr[i].prtName}", Value = arr[i].Count });

        return arr;
    }
 }
```

But as you can see no labels are shown on the X axis.. really don't know how to bypass this problem in order to go on with my work..please can anyone show me the right way?
[image]

Comment: If you check the `DataModel.OnPropertyChanged` you'll see the `CallerMemeberNameAttribute`. This attribute will automatically get the calling memeber name. So you don't nee to pass the property name as string to this method. Generally use `nameof` instead of magic strings: `string propertyName = nameof(this.MyProperty);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow looks broken:
you first initialize the chart data from the constructor by calling `InitializeBarChartData()`, which also initializes the `ColumnLabels` collection. *Then* you create the underlying `ErrorPtr` items, which are the provider of the data for the column labels.
The result is that the `ColumnLabels` property is empty => no labels will be displayed.

Because you add the new `ErrorPtr` items to the `values` field and this field is of type `ChartValues` and this collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the chart will reflect those changes. You were lucky here.

But because you never update the `ColumnLabels` property after you have created the `ErrorPtr` items, the initially (*after* calling `InitializeBarChartData` from the constructor) empty `ColumnLabels` collection remains empty.

### Solution 1

Fix the flow of your data model initialization and call `InitializeBarChartData` *after* `PrtCount`:

```
public ErrorPrt[] PrtCount(List<DataRow> rows)
{
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DataRow>> grouped = rows.GroupBy(s => s.Field<string>(2));
    ErrorPrt[] err = new ErrorPrt[grouped.Count()];
    //Omitted code for sake of brevity
    
    ErrorPrt[] arr = err.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
        this.values.Add(new DataModel() { Label = $"PRT {arr[i].prtName}", Value = arr[i].Count });

    // Initialize the chat models.
    // NOW the label data (the ErrorPrt.prtName) is generated 
    // and ready to be extracted from the ErrorPrt instances
    InitializeBarChartData();

    return arr;
}
```

---

### Solution 2 (Recommended)

Since all involved collections implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` you can dynamically update every collection when new data arrives. You don't need to initialize the complete chart data like the `SeriesCollection` and the `Mapper` or the label formatter over and over again (like in *Solution 1* - in case `PrtCount` will be called more than once).
You can continue to call `InitializeBarChartData` once from the constructor, like you are currently doing it.

Simply don't only update the `values` field, but also the `ColumnLabels` property:

```
public ErrorPrt[] PrtCount(List<DataRow> rows)
{
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DataRow>> grouped = rows.GroupBy(s => s.Field<string>(2));
    ErrorPrt[] err = new ErrorPrt[grouped.Count()];
    //Omitted code for sake of brevity
    
    ErrorPrt[] arr = err.Where(c => c != null).ToArray();        

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
    {    
        var newDataModel = new DataModel() { Label = $"PRT {arr[i].prtName}", Value = arr[i].Count };

        // Here you update the column values
        // and add the new items to the existing items of previous calls
        this.values.Add(newDataModel);

        // Also update the labels whenever new column data has arrived
        this.ColumnLabels.Add(newDataModel.Label);
    }

    return arr;
}
```